# Click Event Always getting only the last instantiated object (C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I know this maybe a duplicate of [How to detect click/touch events on UI and GameObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects) but I tried actually what's in there . But my problem still exists.

Here's my code

```
GameObject o = null;
private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        o = Instantiate(obj) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_obj);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        o.transform.name = "chips " + i;
       
        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);

        UIGridReposition(UIGrid.Sorting.Vertical, true);
    }
}
```

This line of code above is how I instantiate my sprites and it is like this on my heirarchy

> chips 1
>
> chips 2
>
> chips 3
>
> chips 4
>
> chips 5

Now when i try to put this line of code in the `UI Button`

```
public void TestClickEvent(){
   Debug.Log("This object is :" + o.transform.gameobject.name);
}
```

Now when I click on the Instantiated object only `chips 5` will only be the output on my console. Even if i click the first,second etc `Instantiated Object`

Can someone please help me .

What I am trying to do is to get the designated number of each `Intantiated Object` for example

If i click `chips 1`  then it will output `This object is : 1`;

Comment: I put the `Button button = o.GetComponent<Button>()` below the for loop is it right @Programmer

Comment: @Programmer By the way sir it is a `sprite` that has a `ui button`

Comment: yes im using NGUI so your code is not possible sir?

Comment: That's odd. I'm not entirely sure about NGUI. But somewhere in the code is a call to `TestClickEvent()', which is being assigned to all buttons, pointing to the last instantiated object. If that's all your code, then it would seem it's in `NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);`, but that makes no sense.

Comment: You have to post a screenshot of the GameObject with the components attached to it. Forget it if you're using NGUI since I haven't worked with that for a long time and no longer use it. This will oonly work with Unity's UI

Comment: So its still useless i guess . Because I am using NGUI

Comment: @Programmer I saw this post and you helped him actually . [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579727/raycast-wont-hit-collider-after-using-ngui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579727/raycast-wont-hit-collider-after-using-ngui) . But can figure out the rest of the code he used

Comment: I know you found a solution but I think you should be using the built-in event system instead of raycast when detecting clicks on UI objects.. I dug through my old code and found something. If that doesn't work then use your raycast method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution instead of `Camera.main` I tried `UICamera.currentCamera` instead

```
public void TestClickEvent()
{
    Vector2 point = UICamera.currentCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Ray ray = UICamera.currentCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
    {
        Debug.Log("I hit something :" + hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using NGUI and the way to detect click event is totally different than the way you would with Unity's UI. When detecting a click, a raycast may work but is not the recommend way to do so. Always use the callback events for that.

You can do this with `UIEventListener`.

```
GameObject o = null;
private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        o = Instantiate(obj) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_obj);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        o.transform.name = "chips " + i;

        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);

        UIEventListener.Get(o).onClick += TestClickEvent;

        UIGridReposition(UIGrid.Sorting.Vertical, true);
    }
}

void TestClickEvent(GameObject sender) 
{ 
    Debug.Log("Clicked: " + sender.name); 
}
```

There is really no clear examples for NGUI out there so expect to go through a lot of stuff to complete a simple task.

Comment: I'll try this one because on box collider 2d my solution doesn't work